# seam i18n properties file from external jar

Tags: java, jsf, properties, internationalization, seam

I'm trying to load i18n properties file via `core:bundle-names` tag in seam `components.xml` conf file. If I reference a properties file within war project, it's eventually loaded and I can access values from facelets with `#{messages['theKeyValue']}` EL. However, I want to load one from external ejb.jar (which I packed) but no luck. Is there anyone who found a solution for this? I don't want to paste this file all over the projects which use this ejb jar.

PS: I'm using Seam 2.2.2-Final and JSF 1.2_12

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use facelets, you can declare the bundle in the page

```
<f:loadBundle basename="path.in.the.jar" var="messages"/>
```

Comment: Thanks dude, I have bias to f:loadbundle but I added it to my template.xhtml, and it works like a charm.